# Include joined children with Elasticsearch GET request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index `events` that has a join field so that an event can have multiple instances (i.e. the same event can occur on different dates). In this simplified mapping, an `event` doc has fields for `title` and `url` while an `instance` doc has start/end date fields:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "dt": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "end_dt": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "event_or_instance": {
        "type": "join",
        "eager_global_ordinals": true,
        "relations": {
          "event": "instance"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to get an `event` and includes all of its instances using `has_child`:

```json
GET /events/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "c8871a79-1907-46c0-958c-9731c529b93e"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child" : {
            "type" : "instance",
            "query" : { "match_all": {} },
            "inner_hits" : {
              "_source": true,
              "sort": [{"dt": "asc"}]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": true
}
```

This works fine, but is there a way to do this using the Get/Multi-get API instead of the Search API?

Comment: You mean with a multi search to get independent instance hits instead of all instances inside the inner_hits of the parent document ?

Comment: No, with the [Get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html). It seems inefficient to use the Search API to just get documents. (I'm using joins instead of nested documents for other reasons, BTW.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant multi-get... so you want to get the parent document by ID and then multi-get all child documents using the id of the parent?

Comment: Basically, yes. I'm guessing this can't be done without performing an actual search, though.

Comment: But I'm curious to know what you're afraid of? Are your searches slow?

Comment: Not slow at the moment, but the elastic.co documentation on anything relating to joins (`has_child`, `has_parent`) recommends using them sparingly since they're so expensive.

Comment: They also recommend to rethink your data architecture, the ultimate goal being to stop thinking relational and denormalize your data

Comment: Sadly, the join is unavoidable in my case. Using nested documents wouldn't allow me to do things like query the event instances (including pagination, sorting, and filtering) as if they were top-level documents.